# how to import json data in neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j

I have json data and i want to import in neo4j.

Export data option will be there in neo4j but how to import JSON data in neo4j.

```
This is the link of jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/harmeetsingh090/mkdm4t44/
```

Please help if someone know.

Comment: There is no magic in every programming language/database systems/or the real life. You open your favorite programming language editor, you create a script that read your json file and you create yourself statements for creating nodes in relationships. AFAI remember, I did the same for mysql, oracle, redis, riak, mongodb, ...

Comment: Yes, you have to write your own script/program to get it into another format.

Comment: A clean way to do this, and perhaps an efficient automatic tool to do this, sound useful.  Sparse (and bootstrappy) methods suggest uniform random sampling/threadsearching the source store to map out source relationships then some mathemagical derivation of minimum entropy (or kl-divergence, or AIC) graph representation and then import to that.

Comment: so there is no such API to ingest json to neo4j yet (may be with some standard keys specifying which are nodes and which are relationships or may be something else to help ingestion) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4J doesn't have a native way of doing this, but there is a plugin for Neo4J called apoc.load.json. You can load data doing the following:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///<path_to_file>/example.json") YIELD value as document
UNWIND document.root AS root
MERGE (e:ExampleNode {id: root.id})
...
```

You can find more information on the plug here: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/. I've recently used this and found it to be quite intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to manipulate your data into CSV format and then use the [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) command.

Comment: so there is no such API to ingest json to neo4j yet (may be with some standard keys specifying which are nodes and which are relationships or may be something else to help ingestion) ?